# PHP version different to CLI version using Homebrew MacOS Monterey

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, macos-monterey

I have installed PHP with homebrew, switch to PHP 8.0 but the browser phpinfo() is showing 7.4. I am on the latest version of Monterey.

`brew services stop httpd` is stopping the apache service.

```
% php -v
PHP 8.0.19 (cli) (built: May 12 2022 02:25:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.19, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.19, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

```
% which php
/opt/homebrew/bin/php
```

How would I get PHP 8.0 to work in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

in your httpd config, you must hardwire the shipped php version (7.4), with apache, would look like this :

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

Just change the httpd config to load the appropriate lib, and restart your httpd server. Also, php has multiple configs (cli, fpm) : make certain that you tailor the appropriate one in your configs , typically found in /usr/local/etc/php/8.N  (monterey, brewed-in php)